# Adding count information to mapreduce output

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have data that came from sys.stdout mapper.py program as follows:

input from stdout of previous mapper.py

```
chevy, {mod: spark | col: brown}
chevy, {mod: equinox | col: red}
honda, {mod:civic | col:black}
honda, {mod:accord | col:white} 
honda, {mod:crv | col:pink} 
honda, {mod:hrv | col:gray} 
toyota, {mod:corola | col:white}
```

I would like to write a reducer.py or maybe even another mapper that takes this information and produces an output such as:

Expected output

```
chevy, {mod: spark | col: brown | total:2}
chevy, {mod: equinox | col: red | total:2}
honda, {mod:civic | col:black | total:4}
honda, {mod:accord | col:white | total:4} 
honda, {mod:crv | col:pink | total:4} 
honda, {mod:hrv | col:gray | total:4} 
toyota, {mod:corola | col:white | total:1}
```

the `total` is only for the keys (car brand), so `chevy` appears twice, `honda` appears 4 times, and `toyota` 1.

I have tried a reducer.py program and it did not work. The program I wrote looks like this:

```
curr_k = None
curr_v = None
k = None
curr_count = 0

for car in sys.stdin:
    car_split = car.split('|')
    k = car_split[0]
    v = car_split[1]

    if curr_k == k:
        print(curr_k, curr_v, 'total:',curr_count)
        curr_count += 1

    else:
        if curr_k:
            print(curr_k, curr_v, 'total:',curr_count)
        curr_k = k
        curr_count = 1
    
if curr_k == k:
    print(curr_k, curr_v, 'total:',curr_count)
```

The above code gave me the following answer:

```
chevy, {mod: spark | col: brown | total:1}
chevy, {mod: equinox | col: red | total:2}
honda, {mod:civic | col:black | total:1}
honda, {mod:accord | col:white | total:2} 
honda, {mod:crv | col:pink | total:3} 
honda, {mod:hrv | col:gray | total:4} 
toyota, {mod:corola | col:white | total:1}
```

But that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Why should `chevy, {mod: spark | col: brown}` produce a total of 2? There's only one row with that information.

Comment: @Ben, the count is only for the keys. So chevy appears twice, honda appears 4, and toyota is 1. I hope that helps clarify?

Comment: Please show the original input data. Otherwise, seems your `k` values end up like `chevy, {mod: spark`

Answer (score 0):

At the time you print each total, you're only accounting for the lines you've seen up-to that point.

You need to read **all** lines, capturing the correct "total", **then** print all output. You will need to use dictionaries and lists to do this, as shown in your [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74196716/filter-data-and-use-information-of-one-filter-to-fill-the-second-filter).