# Filter Data and use information of one filter to fill the second filter

Tags: python

I would like to know how to write a program to filter data into two filters. The first filter has all data with length of 2 and the second has all data with length of 3. After I get that, I would like to populate the filter with length 2 with the third information from those data with length 3 and prints all data again but this time both filters having 3 information.

See more details below:

This is the data that came in as the output from a previous program with 8 rows.
Assuming this input is called "computers"

```
'dell' | {'year': 2011, 'mem': 12}
'dell' | {'year': 2006, 'mem': 12} | 2
'hp' | {'year': 2018, 'mem': 4} | 1
'asus' | {'year': 2016, 'mem': 11}
'asus' | {'year': 2010, 'mem': 11}
'asus' | {'year': 2021, 'mem': 11} | 3
'lenovo' | {'year': 1998, 'mem': 3} | 1
'mac' | {'year': 2019, 'mem': 3} | 1
```

The third numbers "2, 1, 3, 1, and 1) are counts of each key group. My current program looks like this

```
for computers in sys.stdin:
try:
    computers = computers.strip().split('|')
    if len(computers)==2:       #for computer records that have length of two 
        tKey1 = computers[0]
        mData1 = computers[1]
    else:                   #for computer records that have length of three
        tKey2 = computers[0]
        mData2 = computers[1]
        frequency = computers[2]

    print(computers,frequency)
except:
    pass
```

This gives me an output of

It takes the first record away or eliminates it and produces the following 7 items instead of 8

```
'dell' , {'year': 2006, 'mem': 12} , 2
'hp' , {'year': 2018, 'mem': 4} , 1
'asus' , {'year': 2016, 'mem': 11} , 1
'asus' , {'year': 2010, 'mem': 11} , 1
'asus' , {'year': 2021, 'mem': 11} , 3
'lenovo' , {'year': 1998, 'mem': 3} , 1
'mac' , {'year': 2019, 'mem': 3} , 1
```

However, the expected output I need should look like the following.

The logic is if the computer[0] in the filter with length 2 is same as computer[0] in filter with length 3, use the third item of filter length 3 (in this case the count) as the third item for the filter with length 2.

```
'dell' , {'year': 2011, 'mem': 12} , 2 
'dell' , {'year': 2006, 'mem': 12} , 2
'hp' , {'year': 2018, 'mem': 4} , 1
'asus' , {'year': 2016, 'mem': 11} , 3
'asus' , {'year': 2010, 'mem': 11} , 3
'asus' , {'year': 2021, 'mem': 11} , 3
'lenovo' , {'year': 1998, 'mem': 3} , 1
'mac' , {'year': 2019, 'mem': 3} , 1
```

I don't want to put the data inside a dictionary or a list.

Thank you for your contributions.

Comment: Why are you using `.split('\t')` instead of `.split('|')`?

Comment: Also, your code should throw an error that `frequency` is not defined in your print statement. That being said, it should only print 5 records that actually have a frequency.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I corrected the error in my question.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, the "frequency is not defined" error was the reason I used "try" and "except" and that doesn't give any error message

Comment: Okay, but still, the shown input would generate 5 lines, not 7

Comment: @OneCricketeer, how then can I arrive at the expected output? I need help here.

Comment: Explain to me first how you get 7 lines with that code, as you stated

Comment: Also explain what happens when you have more than one row of length 3 for any of length 2. Do you take the max frequency? The "last" frequency? The first? The min? The average?

Answer (score 0):

> filter data into two filters

Your if statement will handle that fine. You don't need a try-catch since you could add a print statement to the else statement, where only `frequency` is defined.

> don't want to put the data inside a dictionary or a list

You need to. Otherwise, you will be unable to track lines other than the current.

> if the computer[0] in the filter with length 2 is same as computer[0] in filter with length 3, use the third item of filter length 3 (in this case the count) as the third item for the filter with length 2

That logic implies that you've ***already read*** data with "length 3". Therefore, you need to buffer/cache data of "length 2" until you have "existing, matching records" of "length 3" to set the frequency.

As shown...

```
import ast

len2 = dict()
len3 = dict()

for computers in sys.stdin:
    # parse the line
    computers = [
        ast.literal_eval(x.strip()) for x in computers.strip().split('|')
    ]
    # ignore lines without 2-3 elements
    if not (2 <= len(computers) <= 3):
        continue
    # extract elements
    k = computers[0]
    data = computers[1]
    frequency = 0
    if len(computers) == 3:
        frequency = computers[2]
        # if key has already been seen from previous lines
        if k in len3:
            len3[k][0].append(data)  # preseve this line data to output later
            len3[k][1] = frequency  # override frequency with this, "most recent" line
        else:  # store the line for later
            attributes = [data]
            # now that a 3-length line has been seen, can empty out all previous 2-length lines
            if k in len2:
                attributes.extend(len2[k])
                # and we can delete it
                del len2[k]
            len3[k] = (
                attributes,
                frequency,
            )
    else:  # line of length 2
        # if already seen in 3-length data
        if k in len3:
            # store it with the existing frequency
            len3[k][0].append(data)
        elif k in len2:  # seen previously 2-length line
            len2[k].append(data)
        else:  # brand new 2-length line
            len2[k] = [data]

# it's possible you have data that didn't match, so print that out
if len(len2) > 0:
    print('WARN: 2-length lines remaining not seen in 3-length lines')

# after iterating all input lines, output the expected data
for k, v in len3.items():
    data, frequency = v
    for x in data:
        print(', '.join(map(str, [k, x, frequency])))
```

#### Output

```
dell, {'year': 2006, 'mem': 12}, 2
dell, {'year': 2011, 'mem': 12}, 2
hp, {'year': 2018, 'mem': 4}, 1
asus, {'year': 2021, 'mem': 11}, 3
asus, {'year': 2016, 'mem': 11}, 3
asus, {'year': 2010, 'mem': 11}, 3
lenovo, {'year': 1998, 'mem': 3}, 1
mac, {'year': 2019, 'mem': 3}, 1
```

**NOTE**: Obviously since you'd need to buffer the entire input to collect 3-length lines, this will only work with a limited sized dataset...